# weird usage of "von wegen"

Tags: modal-particle

> Komm mir jetzt nicht **von wegen**!

I studied the meanings of "von wegen" on DWDS.de and I still didn't grasp what this means. Plz help.

Comment: Could you specify where you found this? It doesn't seem to make sense on it's own, but, as Janka wrote, it's quite commonly used coloquially with something following, like a citation. "Und komm mir jetzt nicht von wegen 'Ich hab kein Geld.' Du hast genug Geld dafür!"

Answer (score 2):

It's

> Komm mir jetzt nicht von wegen …!

which you could translate as

> Don't tell it's about …!

It does indeed not tell what we are talking about — this has to be guessed from context. A more common variant is

> Komm mir jetzt nicht von wegen keine Zeit!

> Don't tell it's about missing spare time!

and similar adverbials.

That *von wegen + Nominativ* is an odd thingie you won't find outside of speech. In writing and more elaborated speech, it's a regular adverbial *von wegen + Genitiv* that means almost the same as *wegen + Genitiv*, with a bit emphasis.

> Wegen des Urlaubs frage ich später nochmal.

> Von wegen des Urlaubs frage ich später nochmal.

Comment: There are some strange translations here. You need "me" after "don't tell" for this to make sense (assuming I understand). I think the translation you might be looking for in your example is: "Don't (even) tell me you didn't have time!"

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think the phrase is corrupted (as spoken language often is) and should read as: *Komm mir jetzt nicht **mit "von wegen"**!*</del>

<del>Given that the meaning would be something like "Now don't dare to contradict me!"</del>

see comments

Comment: No, that's not what it means.

Comment: @Janka From your answer I see it's is some regional expresson I am not familiar with. From the original question I inferred that the phrase was complete but corrupted. But still I am not sure what it actually means. Is "Komm mir jetzt nicht von wegen keine Zeit!" the same as "Behaupte nicht, dass du keine Zeit hast"?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: I think I get it now. Seems to be a mixture of "Komm mir nicht damit!" and "Von wegen!". A tautology on sentence level, so to say ;-)